# How to force the definition of a destructor

Tags: oop, fortran, abstract-class, finalization

I would like to force inheriting classes to define a destructor in Fortran >= 2008.

So far I have tried several variations of:

```
type, abstract :: parent_class_t
contains
    final, deferred, pass :: cleanup
end type
```

which don't even compile.
How do I achieve that goal?

Comment: Abstract types [cannot have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48788976/3157076) a final subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final bindings are NOT inherited. Every type can declare its own. When a an child derived type is finalized, the parent finalization procedure is called automatically. Abstract types cannot have a final subroutine because it would not make sense.

The standard (2018 draft) contains this explanation note:

> **NOTE 7.46** 
>   Final subroutines are not inherited through type extension
>   and cannot be overridden. The final subroutines of the parent type are
>   called after any additional final subroutines of an extended type are
>   called.

As francescalus notes, the syntax is:

R753 *final-procedure-stmt* is `FINAL` [ :: ] *final-subroutine-name-list*

no attributes may be specified.